# Play Framework - save()

Tags: playframework

The `save()` method is used only to add an entry to the db, not when it is modified. Eg., when I create a question, I do `question.save`. When I add an answer to the question, I just do `question.add(answer)`. I don't have to `save()` the question to save the changes. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: you're not very specific about versions or what database package you're using. You probably do have to save, though. Would be easy to try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you do need to save your question. Play has some pretty good [tutorials](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide2), you should have a look.

Comment: The play docs don't do that: playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide4 (the section on adding the comment form)

Comment: Look at the Post.addComment example from the tutorial link. You can add save in your addAnswer.

Answer (score 2):

Play uses `save()` regardless of whether it is new or existing model. It manages all the complexity of this for you behind the scenes.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I have to save the question everytime I add an answer to it? That's what I thought, but the play docs don't do that: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide4 (the section adding the comment form)

Comment: its does, just not here. In the code, where it calls `post.addComment`, within the `addComment` method, it actually calls `this.save()`, therefore automatically saves itself to the database, including the comment that has just been added.